# Jenkins - How to block build streams?

Tags: version-control, build, jenkins

**Question:** Is there a way to block a build stream if another build stream is in the process of building?

Here is what I'm trying to do. I have two build streams that contain multiple jobs. I can block the jobs up or down stream a given stream. I cannot however block a build stream if the other build stream is building.

**Here is my setup:**

**Build Stream 1:** A1 -> B1 -> C1
**Build Stream 2:** A2 -> B2 -> C2

Job **A1** and **A2** are setup using the SCM plugin to poll separate locations in our repo. So a build can be trigger at any time it finds a change. The build streams should  be treated independently but block if the other have jobs building.

I've tried **Build Blocker Plug-in** but problem is that it **only** blocks if a job or jobs are currently building. It doesn't seem to care about the other builds waiting in the build queue.

I'm limited on the number of resources that are provided to me so I'm having to double up on our builds.

Comment: Can you accomplish what you want by restricting to a single executor?

Comment: I've tried but failed at that ... Maybe I can parametrize each build stream and then depending on that branch changes in our repo supply that as the parameter to the build? ::I really don't know::

Answer (score 2):

The [Exclusion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusion-Plugin) may be able to help you here.

What you would do is set up two other jobs to manage the build trains, M1 job will have build steps that do the following:

1. Grab the semaphore
2. Trigger A1
3. Wait for C1 to finish
4. Release the semaphore

M2 job will be similar

1. Grab the semaphore
2. Trigger A2
3. Wait for C2 to finish
4. Release the semaphore

You would need timeouts, but that is essentially the idea